# Journalize operations done on objects in database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, logging, statistics

I wonder if there is a java framework to journalize operations done on objects and then save them in database.

In fact, I'm working on an application where a particular object undergo many operations, each one is changing its logic (many conrols may be applicated on the object depending on user).

Now, I would like to trace controls or operations done on this object and store them in new tables serving just for statistics. I think that this could be implemented without modifying the whole exiting code of the application. I mean it could be seen as a vertical layer...

I have already seen the description of hibernate interceptors but I'm not sure that it could meet my needs

I would like also to precize that I'm working with spring core and hibernate..

Anyone has an idea about a java framework or an API meeting my need

thanks in advance..

Comment: -> http://envers.jboss.org/ please note that questions asking for libraries, tools etc. are typically considered off-topic for SO.

Comment: thanks, I did not know it, this is duly noted

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure `Hibernate Interceptors` can be helpful for you. But, there is a little change that your entities might have to go through, because interceptors work when saving all the entities, you have to let the interceptor know that you are not interested in saving a few of them by adding custom annotations to them.

Other ways of doing is by using `Spring AOP`, you can log work without touching any of your code, but for this to happen, you need to be using spring in your environment already.

Other ways could be using `traditional Servlet` filters to do this.

There is a concept of `Hibernate Event handlers`, you may also look it up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I confirm I work with spring but when I talked about operations I did not mean CRUD ones done on the object but controls done when object transits in application methods and that are not stocked eventuelly in entity propreties (TABLE if you want)